# C# My OpenReadCompleted Event just doesnt work

Tags: c#, events, stream, webclient

```
public Bitmap SaveImage(string url)
{

    WebClient client = new WebClient();


    client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;



    Stream stream = client.OpenRead(url);
    Bitmap bitmap; bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);


    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();
   // client.Dispose();





    return bitmap;
}

void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Result.ToString());
}
```

When ever it download the image,
the MessageBox dont show

why the OpenReadCompleted event doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) under "Remarks" this only works on asynchronous operations.

Instead of using `OpenRead(url)` you'll want to use `OpenReadAsycn(url)`.

`OpenReadAsync` returns void, so you'll need to do operations on the bitmap inside the `client_OpenReadCompleted` function.

Let me know if I can explain better.